# Want to use python with CATIA? This approach CATIA = win32com.client.Dispatch("CATIA.Application") giving me an error?

Tags: scripting, python-3.6, catia

I am trying to write scripts for CATIA with python(I already used VBA but here I need to do with python only). My code looks like this:

```
 import win32com.client.dynamic
 import numpy as np

 CATIA = win32com.client.Dispatch("CATIA.Application")
 documents1 = CATIA.Documents
 partDocument1 = documents1.Add("Part")
 part1 = partDocument1.Part
```

Error is :

```
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, 
pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)

com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

For any help or suggestion thanks in advance!

Disclaimer: I have checked some similar examples but couldn't find my answer.
[For Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998761/create-new-product-in-catia-with-python/51072543#comment93003616_51072543)
[Similar question but without the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610628/catia-macro-from-python)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your CATIA DLLs are unregistered. If this is the case, you can register them by running the following from a PowerShell prompt as administrator:

```bsh
& "<CATIA installation path>\win_b64\code\bin\V5RegServer" -set CATIA
```